# Bootstrap Layout - Remove Responsiveness

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to create a fixed layout and using Bootstrap for mainly the Javascript Plugins. But the Layout breaks when i try to resize below the 1000px.

> http://mink7.com/projects/test/index.html

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Bootstrap CSS you have included I believe has the responsive elements in it. If you look at Bootstraps website, they include both versions in their source code.

```
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The simplest way to do it would just include the `boostrap.css` file and not `bootstrap-responsive.css`

Comment: i have removed it. Yet the same problem. not sure why

Comment: Your bootstrap css file returns a not found error. `http://mink7.com/projects/test/css/bootstrap.css`, are you sure you have it included?

Comment: Jako sorry was reupping the files.. try now

Comment: Try getting rid of the `<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your header.

Comment: It looks like it has to do with your `<div class=wrapper>` area. I tried to work on it locally and found that by adding, `<div class=wrapper style="width: 1000px">` fixed the issue or if you deleted everything before `<div id=dashboard>` got rid of the issue too. It's something with your wrapper class.

Comment: since the header element i want it to flow all along. i havent given the width. Let me try it out

Comment: thanks. I think the main problem was with the width of the floats inside the header. Thanks a lot :)